# Data correct, but Mailer dont send mail

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have problem with PHP Mailer, Im sure that my data is correct beacuse i used it to test on SMTP Test site, and he sends mail correct, but from Mailer it dont work.

````
require './libs/PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->Host = 'my.server.com';                  // Specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'my@mail.com';                                // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'mypass';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'my@mail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Name';

echo "Mail sended";

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

?>```

Thank you on help in advance.
````

Comment: You don't have a to address or the send.

Comment: "it don't work" is not much info. Did you check some error log. Some error must be logged in somewhere. Or try enabling error display in PHP to see error on page.

Comment: If you think on Mail where it would be sended, its dynamic.. Imagine that its writed up.

Comment: @MilanG Nothing in PHP log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything else, you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

The reason your script is not sending email is because... you're not telling it to.

You have missed out a call to `$mail->send();`.

I can also see you have based your code on an old example, so you might find it easier to start again using the example code provided in the readme.

Comment: Hello, I added it, and still mail not delivered

Comment: I added $mail->send(); under $mail->FromName = ''; but again It's not delivered

Comment: It should be the *last* thing you do, not somewhere in the middle. You've also omitted to set `Body` (so there's nothing to send), and you have no error checking to see where the problem might be. Please do as I suggested and start again with the readme example which makes none of these mistakes; it will be much quicker than fixing the code you have here.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you, it was server delayement.